# Call param inside php script

Tags: php, parameters

I have a php script which can take some GET params. I would like to know how I can call the script with a different param inside the script.

I want to achieve something like this:

```
if ($param == "authorise") {
    //call the same script but use the $param, getAccountDetails"
    i.e http://mywebsite.com/?param=getAccountDetails&var=ivar&foo=bar
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just modify the $_GET array at the top of the script depending on what's inside it:

```
if(isset($_GET['authorise'])){
    $_GET['do_some_secret_thing'] = 'whatever';
}
// run the rest of your logic LIKE A BOSS.
```

There might be some more wizardy way of doing it, but that'd work and is fairly straightforward.

Good luck!

Comment: but how could I initially refresh the page with the new GET? Should I use header()?

Comment: Great way to test things, but can be hard to debug later. @XcodeDev Just call the page with ?param=whatever in the URL.

Comment: This would only work if the `switch`/`if` statement that checks for `'whatever'` is below the `case` or `if` for `'authorize'`. You probably already know this, but just to clarify: Changing the `$_GET` and `$_POST` arrays does not resubmit a request.

Comment: So, using my example, if somebody shows up to index.php?authorize=1, you want to redirect them to index.php?authorize=1&do_some_secret_thing=whatever ? If that's what you want to do, I'd be curious to know why.

Comment: As would I. The point there was to note that if the statement that checks for `do_something_secret=='whatever'` is above the if statement you wrote, the code within the if statement that checks for `do_something secret` would not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use sessions

http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

sessions are used to add information to the client so they can be retrieved later.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing I can think of would be to redirect the user to the script with the new GET variable.

```
if( $_GET['abc'] == 1 ) {
    header( 'Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?abc=2' );
}
```

If you would like to do this without exiting the running PHP script, take a look at [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).